Script for create time-tracking
The question is: all tasks on the project are managed through Features, but time-tracking is stored in the story. Is it possible to make it so that when adding time-tracking to the story, a record is also created  by script in the feature ?

You can automate this scenario with a custom workflow: when a new work item is added to a story, find the related feature and add the same work item there. The latter can be done via the issue.addWorkItem﻿ method.

An exception occurs when using issue.addWorkItem
java.lang.ClassCastException@5a4f2a12
jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2898.invoke(Unknown Source)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.calls.CallerImpl$Method.callMethod(CallerImpl.kt:97)
kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.calls.CallerImpl$Method$Static.call(CallerImpl.kt:106)
.....

Can you please share the full workflow code and the exact exception with our support team? You can do that here: https://jb.gg/ytsup. We'll review it and let you know how to get rid of the exception.
